# Not show duplicated record

Tags: javascript, mysql, record

I have a simply problem: some record of one column of my db are:

- house
- house
- palace
- house
- bar
- palace
- house

I want to show a list without duplicate record like:

- house
- palace
- bar

I use JS to search into my mysql db and if i write this code that show me the first list:

```
    if (Search.EOF) { Response.Write("") }
    else while (!Search.EOF) {

          Response.Write(Search("columnname"))

        Search.Movenext();
    }
```

How can i jump the duplicated record?

Comment: Look at MySQL `distinct` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DISTINCT STATEMENT.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the next query, using **group by**

```
select id, name from table group by name
```